# Anyone have a blog or link to doc for creating GPC VPC 'and' deploying cloudrun for anthos to it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

We use cloud run right now(without anthos).  I am wondering if I can

- Create a VPC
- Deploy cloud run for anthos to that
- Have it so our cloud run instances that talk to external services show a single NAT ip

Is this feasible?  I assume VPC does NOT but not sure how many ips?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just achieve a POC of what you need. I think, you don't need any specific documentation.

- Create a VPC
- Create a [private GKE cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters) with [Cloud Run for Anthos activated](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/gke/setup#create_cluster)
- Create a [Cloud Nat for GKE](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example#step_6_create_a_nat_configuration_using). In this example, you not restrict the subnets and you don't choose your IP, but the Cloud Nat documentation can help you to customize this part. use the `--nat-external-ip-pool=` with existing reserved external IP address.

Just for being precise: your VPC have no IP. Only your VM (your node in your GKE Cluster) have. You can define private subnets with IP Range, but only VM have an private ip in these ranges.

Let me know if you need more guidance.

Comment: AWESOME!!!  I'll have to give it a whirl.  we need to 1. access the cloudrun webpage from external and then 2. our cloud run needs to go through NAT.  2. Is the reserved ip address permanent?  (ie. we hope so as we need to whitelist it)

Comment: If you reserve your External IP and you apply it to your Cloud Nat, it's permanent!